# Get all users of specified AD group returns only one user

Tags: .net-core, filter, active-directory

I need to configure a filter to get all users of specified active directory (AD) group.

Here is my filter:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=name,OU=some ou,DC=mycompany,DC=com))
```

It returns the only one user from the group. It right user, but only one. I need to get all users.

Update: as I'm using the latest .NET Core on Linux, I can't use the `DirectoryServices` namespaces. So I need to do it exactly via filters

Comment: Where else are you getting the member list that makes you think this is incorrect? Is this group the primary group for any of those users? Or are the other members on other domains?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tried and tested method to export all users that are members of an AD group, it includes members of nested groups:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$group = read-host "Please Enter Group Name: "

$gm = @()

$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive
    ForEach ($member in $members) {
        $memberType = $member.objectClass
           If ($memberType -eq 'user') {
              $gm += $member.name
              }
           }
$gm | Out-File c:\temp\$group.txt
```

When executed, it will prompt for the group name.

Comment: as far as I perform this search not as a script, but from .net code, I need to do it only via filter, without loops.

Comment: Apologies, didn't realise you required a language specific solution, please try:

 `(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=memberOf=CN=name,OU=some ou,DC=mycompany,DC=com))`

Comment: what do these numbers mean?

Comment: The numbers are the extended match operator that will ensure that the code will recurse through nested groups.

Comment: it doesn't work for me with number. If I remove these memberOf with numbers it returns again only one record

Comment: Does it always return the same user and is the user that is returned alphabetically first?

Also, made an error in the code above:
`(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=name,OU=some ou,DC=mycompany,DC=com))` Apologies

Comment: it always returns same user. the user is last in list

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace and this code:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mycompany.com", "DC=mycompany,DC=com")  
{

    GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, "Your-Group-Name-Here");  

    if (grp != null)  
    {  
        var members = grp.Members;  
        // do whatever you need to do with those group members
    }  
}
```

If you need not just the direct group members, but also any "recursive" group members (members in other groups that are in this group), you can use

```
    if (grp != null)  
    {  
        var members = grp.GetMembers(true);
        // do whatever you need to do with those group members
    }
```

Comment: it won't work on latest .net core as they have not ported this part of functionality

Comment: @Pyrejkee: you never **mentioned** that you're using **.NET Core** ! You should include such an important information on your **original post** !

Comment: And there **IS** a Nuget package that supports .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Standard 2 : https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/4.7.0 - try to include this!

Comment: will it work with latest .net core on linux machine?

Comment: @Pyrejkee No, it's Windows only.